# Chapter title in RE header and section title on LO for <\fancyhdr>

Tags: fancyhdr, double-sided

I am writing my thesis using `report`documentclass. I want to have current chapter title as 1. Chapter Name on right side of the even page header and section title on left side of the odd page header. I also want to have these headers as smaller cases. Below is my MWE which does not work as I want. On both pages it prints only section names. Can someone tell me what is the problem?

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{report}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\chaptermark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\sectionmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\include{Chapter}
.
.
.
\end{document}
```

I also referred this question which did not help. [Chapter title on even header and section title in odd header](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91445/chapter-title-on-even-header-and-section-title-in-odd-header)

Comment: The title of the question is in contradiction with the body of the question. Which is right?

Comment: Sorry, the body part is right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert a `\pagestyle{fancy}` before the redefinition of `\chaptermark` and `\sectionmark`. The `\chaptermark` in your code sets a left mark and cleans the right mark.  The `\sectionmark` sets a new right mark. So you can use

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{report}

\setlength\headheight{15pt}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}
\fancyhead{}% remove default header entries
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it's simpler to obtain what you want with `titleps` instead of `fancyhdr`. If I've well understood you would have small caps in header instead of regular capital letters:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}}
\usepackage{titleps}
\newpagestyle{mine}{%
\headrule
\setheadrule{1pt}
\sethead[][][\scshape\thechapter. ~\chaptertitle]{\scshape\thesection. ~\sectiontitle}{}{}
\setfoot{}{\thepage}{}
}%
\pagestyle{mine}
\begin{document}%

\chapter{A First Chapter}
\section{Some section}
\lipsum[1-10]

\chapter{A Second Chapter}
\section{Another section}
\lipsum[11-20]

\end{document}
```

[image]